# How to use IFrame player API in amp?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I am creating a sample HTML project using IFrame player API from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#playVideo, and I would like to convert it to AMP version.

I have followed the official docs from https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/, by using `<amp-script>` tag, but it doesn't work. The base.js file includes the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function, and over script:

```
<amp-script layout=container src="/amp/base.js">
<amp-script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api">
<div id="player"></div>
</amp-script>     
</amp-script>
```

The video doesn't appear in the rendering view.

Comment: Why not use [amp-youtube](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-youtube/)?

Comment: Hello @fstanis, I already have used amp-youtube. By setting an "id" the tag, and calling the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function with the same code from the official doc in it, it doesn't work,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the YouTube API if you're using the [`amp-youtube`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-youtube/?format=websites) component. The component runtime will set everything up for you and you can instead use the `play` action to play the video:

```
<amp-youtube id="myVideo" data-videoid="mGENRKrdoGY" layout="responsive" width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>

<button on="tap:myVideo.play">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how to use the play action as you said, I have tried your code, but the play action doesn't play the video. Indeed, I would like to handle the video with Javascript in AMP for some reasons; like in YouTube API, for example, I want to pause the video after 6 seconds... How to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the current API or `amp-script`. I recommend you file an issue at the AMP issue tracker: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues